# org-mode: Inserting custom HTML preamble/postemble to export source

Tags: emacs, org-mode, reveal.js

### Situation

I'm building an `org-reveal` presentation (`.org` file exported to a HTML5 presentation using `reveal.js`). But I want to be able to handle this presentation using a script. In order to embed a script, I need to be able to insert custom HTML elements the exported source code. But I don't want a preamble/postamble defined in `~/.emacs` globally for *all* my presentations - I want to define that custom elements locally in the `.org` file of my presentation

### Question

How can I insert custom HTML elements to the exported source code that way?

Thanks for your answers - if anything's unclear, please leave a comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Org-reveal is just updated, now you can define preamble/postamble locally by setting options "#+REVEAL_PREAMBLE:" and "#+REVEAL_POSTAMBLE:".

The preamble/postamble contents can be also defined by Emacs-Lisp Functions. For a detail instruction, please refer to the Org-reveal's [Readme.org](https://github.com/yjwen/org-reveal/blob/master/Readme.org#preamble-and-postamble)

Answer (score 1):

You can customize the variable `org-publish-project-alist`, see [Org manual](http://orgmode.org/org.html#Sample-configuration).  An example

```
(setq org-publish-project-alist
      '(("site-content"
     :base-directory "/path/to/base-directory"
     :publishing-directory "/path/to/publishing-directory"
     :publishing-function org-publish-org-to-html
     :author "Me"
     :link-home "index.html"
     :html-preamble (concat "INSERT HTML CODE HERE FOR PREAMBLE")
     :html-postamble (concat "INSERT HTML CODE HERE FOR POSTAMBLE"))
    ("site" :components ("site-content"))))
```

Comment: Your suggestion seams like an extension of ‛.emacs‛. When I got this question correctly, then it's about defining a preamble just locally in the regarding ‛*.org‛ file. Any ideas concerning that?

Comment: Something like a local `# eval: (setq org-export-html-preamble-format "HTML CODE HERE")`?

Comment: It doesn't seem like there is a makro called `#+EVAL` in `org-mode`. Maybe you want to specify your suggestion.

Comment: @fdj815 starting from Emacs 24 you can evaluate a Lisp expression when opening a file using the special `eval` file local variable, see the [Emacs manual](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Specifying-File-Variables.html#Specifying-File-Variables).  If you don't want to set `org-publish-project-alist` as suggested by Org manual, I suggest you to set `org-export-html-preamble-format` using an `eval` expression (recall that it requires Emacs 24 at least).